# Shared Calendar Ownership & Admin User

Tags: google-api, google-admin-sdk

I'm looking to do an integration that makes use of a shared calendar for the domain my app is installed on.  My initial plan was to create the calendar under the domain admin that is shared with the rest of the users on the domain.  My concern though is what happens if the domain admin changes?

It seems like that calendar could potentially be lost.  What are the best practices in this circumstance?  Should I be making an admin account for myself at the time of install?  Or should I be creating calendars under my service account?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When admin is changed for a domain, before changing, another admin should be assigned. It cannot happen domain with no admin. So, the new admin gets all the rights to the calendar.

If you want to maintain a single calendar and share with all the users in the domain better go with Admin account.

If you want to have individual calendars to all the users and want to access their calendars, go with service account. With service account you have to do [domain wide delegation](https://developers.google.com/drive/web/delegation) means sharing your service account to the calendar. Also, users initially should give access to the service account to access the information.

Check this [link](https://support.google.com/calendar/answer/143754?hl=en) and this [link](https://support.google.com/a/answer/1626902?hl=en) for calendar sharing options.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  When you mention Admin account in this case do you mean using an existing one on that domain or creating my own?